# How can I stage all changes and commit them without displaying commit-message-buffer in Magit?

Tags: magit

I am trying to write a function which stages all modified files and commits them.

Staging is easy - just run `magit-stage-modified`.

Committing is not - I couldn't find a way of creating a commit without invoking `commit-message-buffer`.

Ideally I'd like to have an interactive function looking like this:

```
(defun just-stage-and-commit (commit-msg)
  ;; ...
  )
```

Any hints? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could always resort to calling `(magit-git-command ARGS DIRECTORY)` with the specific git command you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you provide the `-m` option to `magit-commit` it will use what your provided and not open the message buffer.

```lisp
(defun my-magit-stage-all-and-commit(message)
  (interactive "sCommit Message: ")
  (magit-stage-modified)
  (magit-commit (list "-m" message)))
```

Comment: I think that should be `(magit-commit "-m" message)`

Comment: `magit-commit` takes 1 arg: `(magit-commit &optional ARGS)`, at least in the version I have.

Comment: Ah, right, I got confused, should have been `(magit-commit (list "-m" message))`

Comment: Both will work, but that does look cleaner, I'll use that.